# Matching Month and Year In Python with datetime

Tags: python, django, date, datetime

I'm working on a blog using Django and I'm trying to use get() to retrieve the post from my database with a certain post_title and post_date. I'm using datetime for the post_date, and although I can use post_date = date(year, month, day) to fetch a post made on that specific day, I don't know how to get it to ignore the day parameter, I can't only pass two arguments to date() and since only integers can be used I don't think there's any kind of wildcard I can use for the day. How would I go about doing this?

To clarify, I'm trying to find a post using the year in which it was posted, the month, and it's title, but not the day. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `post_date__year` and `post_date__month`

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is probably coverd by `post_date__year=year` and `post_date__month=month` in django.

Nevertheless all this seems a little bit werid for `get` parameters. Do you have any constraint at database level that forbids you from putting there two posts with the same title in the same month of given year?